# QLabel not displaying in QWidget window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the below piece of code which gives the below picture.

[image]

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sqlite3


class Ui_Form():

    def __init__(self):

        #Checking if the loading database is in place
        if not os.path.exists("loading_database.db"):
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None,'Loading database missing','Loading database has not been found. Creation of a new one will be attempted')
            self.loadingDatabaseCreator()
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None,'Successful','Loading database succesfully created')

        #Asking the user for the input file to be parsed and the number of componenets determined
        filePath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select input model","","Input deck (*.inp)","*.inp")
        filePath = str(filePath)

        self.pleaseWait = waitWindow()
        self.pleaseWait.show()

        #If no file has been inputted the script will exit
        if not filePath:
            exit()
        else:
            #If a file has been inputted now it will be opened and a list containing all the lines will be created
            readInputFile(filePath)

           #Searching in the file for all the valid components. We disregards collectors containing RBE3 elements
           #as they don't require fatigue analysis
            self.pleaseWait.close()
            for line in model_file:
                if "*ELEMENT," in line and "DCOUP3D" not in line:
                    #If a valid collector is found it will be added to the array of type numpy.
                    try:
                        #Checks if the collector has already been recorded as different element types partaining of the same component
                        #will be specified in different collectors win the input deck
                        if not line.split("ELSET=")[1][:-1] in self.collector_array:
                            self.collector_array = np.concatenate((self.collector_array,np.array([line.split("ELSET=")[1][:-1]])),axis=0)
                    except:
                        self.collector_array = np.array([line.split("ELSET=")[1][:-1]])
            #model_file_obj.close

            #Testing to see if the array has been created indicating the presence of at least one entity
            #This will be useful if the user loads a load deck instead of a model as they have the same .inp extension
            try:
                self.collector_array
            except:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None,'Error','File contains no element collectors')

            #Creating the initial Window
            self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.mainWidget.resize(500, 500)
            self.mainWidget.setWindowFlags(self.mainWidget.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
            self.mainWidget.setWindowTitle("nCode analysis set-up")

            #Creating the top level grid layout
            self.mainGrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.mainWidget)

            #Creating the boxes which will describe the analysis to be written in the .dcl file
            self.analysis_type_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainWidget)
            self.analysis_type_label.setText("Type of analysis")
            self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.analysis_type_label,0,0)
            self.analysis_type_combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.mainWidget)
            self.analysis_type_combo.addItems(["Fatigue","Proof plus fatigue"])
            self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.analysis_type_combo,0,1,1,2)
            self.load_deck_type_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainWidget)
            self.load_deck_type_label.setText("Type of fatigue deck")
            self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.load_deck_type_label,1,0)
            self.load_deck_type_combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.mainWidget)
            self.load_deck_type_combo.addItems(["Regen braking","No regen braking"])
            self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.load_deck_type_combo,1,1,1,2)
            self.analysis_engine_type_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainWidget)
            self.analysis_engine_type_label.setText("Analysis Engine")
            self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.analysis_engine_type_label,2,0)
            self.analysis_engine_type_combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.mainWidget)
            self.analysis_engine_type_combo.addItems(["EN analysis","SN analysis"])
            self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.analysis_engine_type_combo,2,1,1,2)

            #Creating a scrolable area to accommodate for a large number of components with possible lenghty names
            self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.mainWidget)
            #The line below is absolutely required to make the scrollable area work.
            self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
            self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.scrollArea,3,0,1,3)
            self.secondaryWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.secondaryWidget)
            self.secondaryGrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.secondaryWidget)

            #This bit creates the necessary object for every componenet that was found in the input deck.
            #The globals method is used to dynamically assign objects to variables for subsequent manipulation.
            for i in range(0, self.collector_array.shape[0]):
                globals()["self.materialLabel"+str(i)] = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.secondaryWidget)
                globals()["self.materialLabel"+str(i)].setText(self.collector_array[i]+" material")
                self.secondaryGrid.addWidget(globals()["self.materialLabel"+str(i)],2+i,0)
                globals()["self.materialName"+str(i)] = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.secondaryWidget)
                globals()["self.materialName"+str(i)].setPlaceholderText("Drop material name here")
                globals()["self.materialName"+str(i)].setFixedWidth(150)
                self.secondaryGrid.addWidget(globals()["self.materialName"+str(i)],2+i,1)
                globals()["self.materialPickingButton"+str(i)] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.secondaryWidget)
                globals()["self.materialPickingButton"+str(i)].setText("Pick material")
                globals()["self.materialPickingButton"+str(i)].clicked.connect(self.material_lookup)
                self.secondaryGrid.addWidget(globals()["self.materialPickingButton"+str(i)],2+i,2)

            #Creates the button that connects to the DLC_writer function
            self.createDCL = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.mainWidget)
            self.createDCL.setText("Create DCL")
            self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.createDCL,4,0,1,3)
            self.createDCL.clicked.connect(self.DCL_guide)
            self.mainWidget.show()

class waitWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Info")
        self.resize(600,200)
        self.VLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.message = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.message.setFixedWidth(550)
        self.message.setText("Please wait while input file is being read")
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.message)

class readInputFile():
    def __init__(self,filePath):
        model_file_obj = open(filePath, "r")
        globals()['model_file'] = model_file_obj.readlines()
        model_file_obj.close

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is my text label is missing from this window. I made it so big in case the label did not have enough space to fully display but in that case I think it would have displayed what it had space for. Hopefully someone knows why.

Edit: I have included the entire **init** function of Ui_Form. All my problems are caused in this bit the rest working ok.

Comment: I have tested your code adding the creation of the QApplication and start of the eventloop and I do not see any problem: https://imgur.com/a/7etMYaP . Probably the error is caused by the code that you do not show, so if you want help provide a [mre]

Comment: what is `loadingDatabaseCreator`?

Comment: You are right, the bit of code initially provided does not contain the error. Apologies. I have edited the post with a minimum reproducible example as I am still unclear as to what is causing it. loading database creator is a sub-function of the Ui_Form() class. If you think that bit is also required I will add it. I am just trying to keep it as concise as possible although I understand that being concise without accurately describing the problem is not useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window you are viewing is not pleaseWait window but the mainWidget window.

The above is explained assuming that:

- The file that is read is small, so the pleaseWait window will open and close instantly, so that being that synchronous action Qt will not have time to do it and for the user the window will never have been shown. For this case the solution is to give a reasonable time for the user to see the window.
- The file is very large, the reading will take a long time blocking the eventloop, which will cause tasks such as displaying a window to not be performed, to avoid blocking the task must be executed in another thread.

Combining both solutions we obtain the following code:

```py
import os
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    contentChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def read_file(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "r") as model_file_obj:
            model_file = model_file_obj.readlines()
            print(model_file)
            self.contentChanged.emit(model_file)
        self.finished.emit()


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setWindowFlags(
            self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
        )
        self.setWindowTitle("nCode analysis set-up")
        mainGrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()

        self.m_worker = Worker()
        self.m_worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self.m_worker.contentChanged.connect(self.get_content)

    def launch_task(self):
        if not os.path.exists("loading_database.db"):
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                None,
                "Loading database missing",
                "Loading database has not been found. Creation of a new one will be attempted",
            )
            # self.loadingDatabaseCreator()
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                None, "Successful", "Loading database succesfully created"
            )
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, "Select input model", "", "Input deck (*.inp)", "*.inp"
        )
        self.pleaseWait = WaitWindow()
        self.pleaseWait.show()
        self.m_worker.finished.connect(self.pleaseWait.close)
        wrapper = partial(self.m_worker.read_file, fileName)
        # Launch the task in a reasonable time for the window to show
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, wrapper)  #

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
    def get_content(self, lines):
        print(lines)


class WaitWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Info")
        self.resize(600, 200)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.message = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.message.setFixedWidth(550)
        self.message.setText("Please wait while input file is being read")
        layout.addWidget(self.message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    w.show()
    w.launch_task()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

```py
import os
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setWindowFlags(
            self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
        )
        self.setWindowTitle("nCode analysis set-up")

        self.wait_window = WaitWindow()

        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()

        self.m_worker = Worker()
        self.m_worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self.m_worker.new_content_signal.connect(self.get_content)

        # Creating the top level grid layout
        mainGrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        self.analysis_type_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.analysis_type_label.setText("Type of analysis")
        mainGrid.addWidget(self.analysis_type_label, 0, 0)
        self.analysis_type_combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.analysis_type_combo.addItems(["Fatigue", "Proof plus fatigue"])
        mainGrid.addWidget(self.analysis_type_combo, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        self.load_deck_type_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.load_deck_type_label.setText("Type of fatigue deck")
        mainGrid.addWidget(self.load_deck_type_label, 1, 0)
        self.load_deck_type_combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.load_deck_type_combo.addItems(
            ["Regen braking", "No regen braking"]
        )
        mainGrid.addWidget(self.load_deck_type_combo, 1, 1, 1, 2)
        self.analysis_engine_type_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.analysis_engine_type_label.setText("Analysis Engine")
        mainGrid.addWidget(self.analysis_engine_type_label, 2, 0)
        self.analysis_engine_type_combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.analysis_engine_type_combo.addItems(["EN analysis", "SN analysis"])
        mainGrid.addWidget(self.analysis_engine_type_combo, 2, 1, 1, 2)

        # Creating a scrolable area to accommodate for a large number of components with possible lenghty names
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        # The line below is absolutely required to make the scrollable area work.
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        mainGrid.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 3, 0, 1, 3)
        self.secondaryWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.secondaryWidget)
        self.secondaryGrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.secondaryWidget)

        self.createDCL = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.createDCL.setText("Create DCL")
        mainGrid.addWidget(self.createDCL, 4, 0, 1, 3)

    def start_task(self):
        if not os.path.exists("loading_database.db"):
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                None,
                "Loading database missing",
                "Loading database has not been found. Creation of a new one will be attempted",
            )
            # self.loadingDatabaseCreator()
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                None, "Successful", "Loading database succesfully created"
            )

        filePath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, "Select input model", "", "Input deck (*.inp)", "*.inp"
        )
        if filePath:
            self.wait_window.show()
            self.m_worker.finished.connect(self.wait_window.close)
            wrapper = partial(self.m_worker.read_file, filePath)
            # Launch the task in a reasonable time for the window to show
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, wrapper)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, str)
    def get_content(self, i, content):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("{} material".format(content))
        linedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Drop material name here")
        linedit.setFixedWidth(150)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Pick material")

        self.secondaryGrid.addWidget(label, 2 + i, 0)
        self.secondaryGrid.addWidget(linedit, 2 + i, 1)
        self.secondaryGrid.addWidget(button, 2 + i, 2)


class WaitWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Info")
        self.resize(600, 200)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.message = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.message.setFixedWidth(550)
        self.message.setText("Please wait while input file is being read")
        layout.addWidget(self.message)


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    new_content_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def read_file(self, fileName):
        i = 0
        collector_array = []
        with open(fileName, "r") as model_file_obj:
            for line in model_file_obj.readlines():
                if "*ELEMENT," in line and "DCOUP3D" not in line:
                    t = line.split("ELSET=")[1][:-1]
                    if t not in collector_array:
                        self.new_content_signal.emit(i, t)
                        QtCore.QThread.msleep(10)
                        collector_array.append(t)
                        i += 1
        self.finished.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    w.show()
    w.start_task()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this function indeed works as intended but it is too heavily modified from my original example for re-integration back into the original program. I have been trying since morning to pin-point exactly which bit fixes it but with not a lot of luck. I have gotten rid of a lot of the code provided and the furthest I have gotten is deducing that if I replace `wrapper = partial(self.m_worker.read_file, fileName)` with a normal function call my problem re-appears. But I am not sure if that is actually the problem or how to implement that in my own code.

Comment: @CristianCapsuna Your code is incorrect as indicated in my answer so you must use my code, if instead you have another code then if you do not provide an MRE it is difficult to give an appropriate solution to your code that I do not know.

Comment: I have included the entire __init__  function for more clarity. The main headache for me is the Worker class that you defined as I am not familiar with slots and signals so I don't know how to integrate it. Sorry my stumbling. I'm at the limits of what I know.

Comment: @CristianCapsuna share your .inp file

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @CristianCapsuna Upload it to drive, dropbox, mega, etc and share the link to download it.

Comment: please find it below. It is not my actual .inp file but this dummy should serve the purpose of taking a bit of time to parse as it is roughly the same length and contains some of the things that the script is searching for. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JUeXsWQOdzySNLyu_hg1SRZiSS-AMvLW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @CristianCapsuna I'm only interested in being allowed to execute your code, if so, then it's enough

Comment: it works but it parses a lot faster than the actual file unfortunately. Apologies.

Comment: i made a batter dummy. a small annoying thing is that it will not detect some required files and try to use the functions defined for creating those but they are not actually required for running the init to the end so you can just delete the bit that checks and calls the function stopping the __init__ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Flaq3Tba4lTdkZqO1j5NbJG7kL9y7xCv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's working and I am starting to understand. The last thing I would like to change but don't know how is how to make the `MainWidget` window appear after `WaitWindow`. Is that easy to do?

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly for me:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication


class waitWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Info")
        self.resize(600,200)
        self.VLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.message = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.message.setFixedWidth(550)
        self.message.setText("Please wait while input file is being read")
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.message)
        self.show()

    def closeWindow(self):
        self.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = waitWindow()
w.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay took your code and gutted all the unessential stuff to analyze the actual issue I have included the gutted version so you can see what is necessary in the future to see what is wrong.

In short the issue is that you need to add the following line as the last line in your waitWindow function >>  self.exec()   by adding that I got your label to display (see code below)

Now with that said you do have another issue and that is the QDialog box will not allow the program to continue until it has been closed (aka it stops the process flow until you release it by closing the window or use a different means). My question is why not use your "main window" to display that message then repopulate with the rest of that data.  Also curious why are you not using QMainWindow?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_Form():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pleaseWait = waitWindow()
        self.pleaseWait.show() 

        self.pleaseWait.close()
        sys.exit()

class waitWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(waitWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Info")
        self.resize(600,200)

        self.message = QLabel(self)
        self.message.setFixedWidth(550)
        self.message.setText("Please wait while input file is being read")

        self.VLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.VLayout.addWidget(self.message)

        self.setLayout(self.VLayout)
        self.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: it's counter intuitive for the user to need to close a window that is asking them to wait. don't know how I would close that from the workflow. I use QWidget instead of QMainWindow because I am not a programmer by train and don't know the pros and cons of both. Just trying to do my best with what I know.

Comment: Personally I would not use QDialog box as I stated if you use a QMainWindow (or do something similar to this) you can create 2 center panes and use the first to display your wait message and then when done replace that with the completed 2nd center pane that holds all your other stuff -- note there are a myriad of ways to implement this but yes it is counter-intuitive that is why I mentioned it when I noticed what it was going to do.